# How to detect if a disk is seeking?

Tags: linux, disk, measure

I can use a variety of tools to measure the volume of disk I/O currently flowing through the system (such as `iotop` and `iostat`) but I'm curious if it's possible to easily detect if a disk is seeking a lot with only a small amount of I/O.

I know it;s possible to extract this information using `blktrace` and then decode it using `btt` but these are somewhat unwieldy and I was hoping there was a simpler alternative?

Comment: Put your ear close to your drive? :)

Comment: Shouldn't a low ratio `(rkB/s + wkB/s)/%util` signify that the disk is seeking (in `iostat -x`)?

Comment: Do you want a tool that shows this live or are you looking to look at the data over a given period of time?

Comment: AFAIK, https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/iostats.txt are the only stats maintained by the kernel, so I don't expect you'll find better than blktrace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ratio `(rkB/s + wkB/s)/%util` of the `iostat -x` output should give you
some insight:

```
Device:  rrqm/s wrqm/s   r/s   w/s  rkB/s  wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda        0.04   3.65  7.16  6.37 150.82 212.38    53.71     0.03  1.99    0.82    3.31   0.76   1.03
```

I'm not sure how exactly this ratio corresponds to the disk seek. But the idea
is that, if the disk is busy and does not have a high throughput it is
probably seeking. However, it's not guaranteed. Broken disks sometimes show a
high utilisation and have almost no throughput. But it's at least an
indicator.

You can also provide a number to iostat (e.g. `iostat -x 5`) to specify the update interval. That
way you can monitor continuously.

Comment: Presumably, many read requests paired against a low rkB/s would be indicative of such a situation

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if you're looking for tools that show this type of information in a real-time type of way or over a period of time, but here are 2 tools that show the real-time aspects of the disk being accessed.

#### nmon

You invoke it like so, `nmon`. Then once it's open you hit the <kbd>j</kbd> (Filesystems) followed by a <kbd>d</kbd> (Disk I/O Graphs D=Stats). See the built-in help (<kbd>h</kbd>) for more details.

```
$ nmon
┌nmon─13g─────────────────────Hostname=manny────────Refresh= 2secs ───11:15.32─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Filesystems ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────│
│Filesystem            SizeMB  FreeMB %Used Type     MountPoint                                                                    │
│v/mapper/ubuntu-root 465389.0 457483.9   1.7 ext4     /                                                                           │
│/proc                                      proc     not a real filesystem                                                         │
│/sys                                       sysfs    not a real filesystem                                                         │
│/sys/fs/fuse/connections                   fusectl  not a real filesystem                                                         │
│/sys/kernel/debug                          debugfs  not mounted                                                                   │
│/sys/kernel/security                       security not a real filesystem                                                         │
│/dev                                       devtmpfs not a real filesystem                                                         │
│/dev/pts                                   devpts   not a real filesystem                                                         │
│tmpfs                  740.5   739.4   0.1 tmpfs    /run                                                                          │
│none                     5.0     5.0   0.0 tmpfs    /run/lock                                                                     │
│none                  1851.2  1849.8   0.1 tmpfs    /run/shm                                                                      │
│none                   100.0    99.9   0.1 tmpfs    /run/user                                                                     │
│/dev/sda1              910.9   606.5  33.4 ext2     /boot                                                                         │
│/run/rpc_pipefs                            rpc_pipe fstatfs returned zero blocks!!                                                │
│/run/user/emma/gvfs                        fuse.gvf not mounted                                                                   │
│/run/user/emily/gvfs                       fuse.gvf not mounted                                                                   │
│ Disk I/O ──/proc/diskstats────mostly in KB/s─────Warning:contains duplicates─────────────────────────────────────────────────────│
│DiskName Busy  Read WriteMB|0          |25         |50          |75       100|                                                    │
│sda      100%    0.0   66.4|RWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW>                                                    │
│sda1       0%    0.0    0.0|>                                                |                                                    │
│sda2       0%    0.0    0.0|>                                                |                                                    │
│sda5     100%    0.0   66.4|RWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW>                                                    │
│dm-0     100%    0.0   48.0|RWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW>                                                    │
│dm-1       0%    0.0    0.0|                     >                           |                                                    │
│Totals Read-MB/s=0.0      Writes-MB/s=180.9    Transfers/sec=363.2                                                                │
│──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────│
```

Another tool I've come across that does at least a live view of disk I/O is `atop`.

```
$ atop
ATOP - grinchy                           2013/08/23  11:10:58                           ------                           10s elapsed
PRC | sys    2.18s  | user  26.26s  | #proc    315  | #trun  5 |  #tslpi   764 |  #tslpu     1 |  #zombie    0 |  #exit  1 |
CPU | sys      22%  | user    264%  | irq       0%  | idle    110% |  wait      4% |  guest     0% |  curf 1.20GHz |  curscal  44% |
cpu | sys       5%  | user     76%  | irq       0%  | idle     19% |  cpu003 w  0% |  guest     0% |  curf 1.20GHz |  curscal  44% |
cpu | sys       5%  | user     67%  | irq       0%  | idle     26% |  cpu001 w  2% |  guest     0% |  curf 1.20GHz |  curscal  44% |
cpu | sys       5%  | user     62%  | irq       0%  | idle     31% |  cpu000 w  1% |  guest     0% |  curf 1.20GHz |  curscal  44% |
cpu | sys   7%  | user     58%  | irq   0%  | idle     34% |  cpu002 w  1% |  guest     0% |  curf 1.20GHz |  curscal  44% |
CPL | avg1    3.83  | avg5    4.59  | avg15   4.76  |              |  csw    54101 |  intr   45315 |               |  numcpu     4 |
MEM | tot     7.6G  | free  194.3M  | cache 495.5M  | dirty   2.7M |  buff   38.9M |  slab   86.7M |               |               |
SWP | tot     5.7G  | free    5.5G  |               |              |               |               |  vmcom  12.4G |  vmlim   9.5G |
LVM | nchy-lv_home  | busy     11%  | read       1  | write    524 |  KiB/w      3 |  MBr/s   0.00 |  MBw/s   0.20 |  avio 2.05 ms |
LVM | nchy-lv_root  | busy      1%  | read       0  | write      7 |  KiB/w  4 |  MBr/s   0.00 |  MBw/s   0.00 |  avio 9.00 ms |
DSK |          sda  | busy     11%  | read       1  | write    109 |  KiB/w 19 |  MBr/s   0.00 |  MBw/s   0.20 |  avio 10.3 ms |
NET | transport     | tcpi  72  | tcpo     118  | udpi      15 |  udpo   5 |  tcpao     11 |  tcppo      0 |  tcprs      0 |
NET | network       | ipi       87  | ipo      123  | ipfrw      0 |  deliv     87 |               |  icmpi      0 |  icmpo      0 |
NET | wlan0   ----  | pcki      88  | pcko     123  | si   34 Kbps |  so   19 Kbps |  erri       0 |  erro       0 |  drpo       0 |

  PID  RUID       EUID       THR    SYSCPU    USRCPU   VGROW    RGROW    RDDSK   WRDSK   ST   EXC  S   CPUNR    CPU  CMD         1/4
 3649  saml       saml        34     0.33s    11.98s      0K    1752K       4K   2828K   --     -  R       2   122%  chrome
10399  saml       saml         4     0.14s     3.08s   5120K   -12.8M       0K      0K   --     -  S       2    32%  chrome
```

Specifically these lines that are showing LVM and DSK activity:

```
    LVM | nchy-lv_home  | busy     11%  | read       1  | write    524 |  KiB/w      3 |  MBr/s   0.00 |  MBw/s   0.20 |  avio 2.05 ms |
    LVM | nchy-lv_root  | busy      1%  | read       0  | write      7 |  KiB/w  4 |  MBr/s   0.00 |  MBw/s   0.00 |  avio 9.00 ms |
    DSK |          sda  | busy     11%  | read       1  | write    109 |  KiB/w 19 |  MBr/s   0.00 |  MBw/s   0.20 |  avio 10.3 ms |
```

#### iostat

If you're interested in the data over a period of time, `iostat` is still probably your best option, wrapped into a script. You can get rid of the utilization output so that it's easier to deal with:

```
$ iostat -dx /dev/sda 5
Linux 2.6.35.14-106.fc14.x86_64 (grinchy)   08/23/2013  _x86_64_    (4 CPU)

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               1.82    96.60    3.84   20.68   122.26   891.99    41.36     0.46   18.77   7.35  18.01

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00    26.20    1.60   24.60    17.60   350.40    14.05     0.31   11.95   8.84  23.16
```

#### Directly from the Kernel

This block of code (bash) will show you the read I/O's processed, directly from the Kernel.

```
OLD=`awk '{print $1}' /sys/block/sda/stat` # First field is number of read I/Os processed
DT=1
for ii in `seq 1 10`
do
    sleep $DT
    NEW=`awk '{print $1}' /sys/block/sda/stat`
    echo $((($NEW-$OLD)/$DT))
    OLD=$NEW
done
```

*source: https://serverfault.com/a/525248/2518*

The information can also be had from either `/sys/block/sda/stat` or `/proc/diskstats` in situations where you can't or don't want to install any tools.

#### References

- [Linux Kernel iostats.txt documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/iostats.txt)
- [Linux Kernel stat.txt documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/stat.txt)
- [How can I monitor hard disk load on linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/9428/how-can-i-monitor-hard-disk-load-on-linux)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but the metrics you've provided are still I/O focused, ideally, I'd like to see disk seek activity irrespective of I/O throughput

Comment: @GearoidMurphy - I didn't see a way to get this type of telemetry data about disk accesses outside of I/O.

Comment: I think Marco hit on it in a comment above, the solution would be to look at the ratio of disk transactions to the actual volume of data read/written.

Comment: @GearoidMurphy - yeah that's why I asked for clarification in the comments as to whether you wanted a real-time type of solution or period of time type. If you come up with a workable solution I'd write it up as an answer and accept it. There wasn't a lot when searching for your particular slant on this.